# SQLite3 /Python: Update Query to populate a field by taking the difference from two fields in the same table

Tags: sqlite

My table: tblTest:

```
RunID,StartTime, EndTime, Period
1,2013-03-30 18:08:14-04,2013-04-01 10:57:22-04
2,2013-04-03 12:13:10-04,2013-04-03 18:05:34-04
3,2013-04-04 06:02:30-04,2013-04-05 10:42:00-04
4,2013-04-05 10:43:00-04,2013-04-06 13:23:06-04
```

I am attempting to update the table to calculate the column Period.
The query that I am using is:

```
UPDATE tblTest SET Period = (SELECT strftime('%s',substr(endtime,1,19)) -
                              strftime('%s',substr(starttime,1,19)) From tblTest)
```

but to my surprise it updates all Periods with the same value from the first line.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery like `(SELECT ... FROM tblTest)` without a `WHERE` condition returns all records of the table.
In a context where only one value is expected (like in the `SET` expression), only the first such record is used.

You can just directly access the columns of the table that you are updating:

```sql
UPDATE tblTest
SET Period = strftime('%s', substr(EndTime,   1, 19)) -
             strftime('%s', substr(StartTime, 1, 19))
```